# apache prefork/mod_wsgi spawning processes beyond configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, performance, python

in a production environment running nginx reversing back to apache mpm-prefork/mod_wsgi, im seeing **90** apache child processes, when i would expect that 40 would be the maximum, as configured below. the configuration/setup is nothing exciting:

1. nginx is reverse proxying to apache via `proxy_pass`, and serving static media
2. apache only serves dynamic requests

relevant nginx config:

```
worker_processes 15;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

keepalive_timeout 10;
```

relevant apache config:

```
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100 
KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers        20
    MinSpareServers     7      
    MaxSpareServers     10
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</IfModule>
```

mod_wsgi config, where `webapp` is the name of the process:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess webapp user=www group=users threads=1 processes=40
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Graham Dumpleton may have [answered your question in his blog recently](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html).

**Edit**

I guess I should point out that his blog post is mostly about mod_python, but I think his explanation of how prefork works may give you some insight as to where the additional processes are coming from.

Comment: I have also commented on this same question over on Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913632/apache-prefork-modwsgi-spawned-process-count-seemingly-past-configuration.